# Parse string value to datetime value

Tags: c#

I need to parse string value to date time value, I have date in this format:

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

I want to parse value in this format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date_req, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But i have an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Note: a DateTime struct doesn't hold the date in any particular "format", it just stores years, months, days and so on, as integers. Only when doing a .ToString() some format is used.

Comment: Hans, DateTime just stores an `Int64` of ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is parse your `dd.MM.yyyy` and then display it as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

You first have to parse the `string` into a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(date_req, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now `date` is a representation of the date that the computer actually understands (before it was just a string). You can now display this object anyway you want:

```
string yyyyMMdd = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string arabic = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("ar"));
// and so on
```

Don't forget that when converting dates from strings to `DateTime` and back, culture and time zones are worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string in the format `DD.MM.YYYY` why are you passing `YYYY-MM-DD` to your ParseExact function?

Try like this:

```
string dateStr = "12.06.2012";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then when you want to output this `DateTime` instance somewhere you could use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, like this:

```
string result = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Well I don't know how to do it, and the date is being passed from one datebase to another, in my database is dd.mm.yyyy and in another has to be in yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: ADO.NET should handle DateTime instances correctly. Once you have a valid DateTime instance it will transform to the underlying format if you are using a date column in your database.

Comment: And if it's a 'date' column in both databases, then you shouldn't use a ToString(), just use the value as a (possibly nullable) DateTime value!

Answer (score 1):

When parsing a date you need to specify the format you want to *read*, not the format you want as output later.

So use `dd.MM.yyyy` as argument to `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 1):

> Check [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String,
>   IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)     Converts the specified string representation
>   of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent. The format of the
>   string representation must match a specified format exactly or an
>   exception is thrown.

you have to specify format string as `DD.MM.YYYY` rather than `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

try this:

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(date_req, "DD.MM.YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

// use this when you need to show that formatted date value
string formattedDate = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Better way is that use [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx), if you want it as date rather than string modify your culture info and date separator.

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
string dateString;
DateTime dateValue;
dateString = "05.01.2009"; 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "DD.MM.YYYY", enUS, 
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, 
                     dateValue.Kind);
else
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);
```

Comment: But that string has to be passed to datetime value not to string value

Comment: then change your cultureinfo to get date in such format otherwise it will produce exception.

Comment: I wrote it like this DateTime datereq = DateTime.ParseExact(date_req, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string str = datereq.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            Agr3PL.DataArea.Header.DateDeliveryRequest = DateTime.Parse(str); But the date is still dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: use `string datestring= date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("cultureid"));` e.g. es, de, fr etc

Answer (score 0):

First parse it in the existing format then convert to the string format you want.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(date_req, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
var str = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert it to a character array. then you can parse day/month/year separately to  integers . You know the indexes of the numbers so this will be easy. after that you can concatenate every element in the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Error. You have a cake and you want to eat a stake. In order to convince your stomach that that the cake is a stake you have to transform the cake to a stake. This cannot be done. Parsing is about accepting a value as it comes and use a pattern (or more) to translate it to something else and not transform it. So what you want may be right but you ask is wrong.